# Security on GET with query params

Tags: rest, http

I have a dilemma. What do you return for a GET REST request where a user doesn't have the right to use a certain query param.

For example : `GET /transactions?user=admin`

If an user, that is not the admin tries the following example, what should be the proper response 403 or an empty list?

He has the right to search for any other user, but not the user admin.

Comment: `401` if not logged in (or you want a password prompt) and `403` if not authorized. Some may say `404` so no one can enumerate your admin accounts but that only works if you return `404` for  not found requests... and doesn't really protect much.

Comment: Well 404 would be if u request by id as in transactions/123 and the id is incorrect. What im asking is about a list. Is it still not authorized or i shouldnt bother to check just enforce the user restriction.

Comment: I don't disagree but from a security aspect if you admit that the admin account exists by throwing an unauthorized versus a not found you are allowing a potention security enumeration attack.  (It's not an attack I personally agree is useful to list... but some places will point it out.) http://www.evolution-sec.com/en/products/enumeration-attack-vectors

Comment: Again... it's just a thought and it depends on how important such a vector is to your security team.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_User_Enumeration_and_Guessable_User_Account_(OWASP-AT-002)

Comment: That security concern seems pretty interesting. Ill keep that in mind, i think it could be a problem. Thx for the info

Comment: First, i agree with @MatthewWhited on this, 2nd `Well 404 would ... and the id is incorrect` well incorrect here "technically" means "Not Found", what Matt. says is something like when you try to login with username and password, the website never tells Invalid username or Invalid password, it only tells you Invalid Login, so you don't focus on the incorrect info and brute-force it or something, now when you deny the existence of admin ID for non-authorized Users you protect it,otherwise you are actually telling them: "ok this is a valid ID, but it's an admin ID, so plz don't abuse it"